# Socket programming problem in C

Tags: c, sockets

From the below piece of code, why I am getting Reading Socket for response

```
int Read(int sock, char *p, int size)
{
    int remain, read=0;

    remain = size;
    while (remain > 0 ) {

        if ((read = recv(sock, p, remain, 0)) < 0) {

            /* Error */
            return(read);
         } else if (read == 0 || *p == 0x0a) {

            /* EOF */
            break;
        }
        remain -= read;
        p += read;
    }

    return(size - remain);
}



while (!done)
{
    printf("***Reading  Socket for response***");
    rsplen= Read(myVsHandle.sock,(char *)encXMLResponse,MAX_RSP_LEN);
    if (rsplen < 0 )
    {
        printf("Internal Communication Error");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (rsplen >0)
        printf("Revieved response");
        done++;
        return 0;
    else if (rsplen == 0)
    {
        printf("Reading socket");
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: I want to know if the read() fails then there one of the three condition must be true. Response length > 0, =0 or <0. Is it possible that read() keeps on waiting contineously

Comment: Why it is working for most of the cases?

Comment: Could you please let me know why this has been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for `MAX_RSP_LEN` bytes to be read - is there that many bytes to be read? Maybe your process is stuck in a blocking `read()`.

Also depending on the sort of socket you are `recv()`ing from, there is no guarantee on the amount of data you will read, so specifically looking for a value `0x0a` may not work.

Comment: I can see the response messages of length less than the MAX_RSP_LEN could be read successfully

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that you are not ending your output with a newline.  Try ending your outputs with a newline (`\n`).  `stdout` is line buffered, so you may not see anything for a long time if you don't output a newline.

Another possibility is that you don't return from `Read()` unless you read the specified number of bytes.  Depending upon the value of `MAX_RSP_LEN`, and the amount of data available, `Read()` may wait forever.

Also, your test: `*p == 0x0a` looks suspicious.  What are you testing here?

*Edit*: There is another "bug":

```
else if (rsplen >0)
    printf("Revieved response");
    done++;
    return 0;
else...
```

You are missing curly braces.  In the current form, the code shouldn't compile.  Please post actual code.

Comment: This code is compiled and is working properly for many messages. I wonder why it is keep on waiting for infinite period. If read can read even a zero byte message then the corresponding printf should get executed

Comment: As I said, you are not ending your output with a newline.  So even if the `printf()` call gets called, you may not see any output.

Comment: @Sachin: also, is this the actual code?  You are missing curly braces, but that makes it not compile.  Please post real code.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
if ((read = recv(sock, p, remain, 0)) < 0) {
```

Should be

```
if ((read = recv(sock, p, remain, 0)) > 0) { // Greater then 0, because recv returns the number of bytes received if successful, if it fails -1.
```

Comment: Umm, your comment is correct, but the condition is checking for error, so it should be `< 0`.

Comment: come on, read the code !! he is looping until there is an error or nothing to receive. his test is fine: when `recv()` returns a value < 0, it is an error, as the comment in the code is telling you !

Answer (score -1):

You're missing curly braces around the:

```
else if(rsplen > 0)
    ... statements
```

It should be:

```
...
}else if (rsplen >0){
    printf("Revieved response");
    done++;
    return 0;
} ...
```

Comment: That's most likely an error due to typing the code here on SO, instead of posting actual code.  Otherwise the next `else` is syntax error.

Comment: I have already stated this is working fine for most of the cases in an online system

Comment: Oh, thanks for the downvote, I really appreciate the feedback: I mean, no-one had spotted this error and there were like four answers asking for more information.